# How to view the only the list of region that holds data (non-empty regions) in HBase

Tags: hbase, nosql

I have created a HBase table with Pre-Split strategy for Region Split.

The HBase table created with given input region. We loaded records which lands on certain regions based upon the key provided.

While accessing the table HFile path, all the regions are listed.

How to view the only the list of region that holds data (non-empty regions).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the du of each region, any region has occupied disk is an non-empty regions.

`hadoop fs -du -s /hbase/data/default/<table_name>/*/<column_family>`

For example : The below image shows the first two regions has utilized the disk and last region has zero disk utilization is the empty region

[image]